# Empty trash in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, rm, delete

I'm trying to empty my trash using the UI but it doesn't work. i tried to use this command  `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*` but it does not success with messages like  `rm: cannot remove 'file.txt': Read-only file system. any solution`

Comment: how are you running Ubuntu? live usb, dual-boot?  I've seen where recent Windows upgrades are flipping "fast-boot" back on and locking up drives...

Comment: @bgregs dual boot

Comment: Did you look into the fast-boot issue?  Found it documented here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/668204

Comment: i have discovered that all files on linux are only read not only trush

Comment: @GAD3R all files a es owned by my user

Comment: @bgregs i found that fast boot was activated i turn it off but i can't boot on ubuntu in the grup when i chose ubuntu that's take me to a terminal                     `(initramfs) ls    (got this >)                             dev  init  conf  etc  sbin  proc  root   run   bin  var   lib64   tmp   kernel   lib   usr   scripts      sys `

Comment: It sounds like you're making progress!  Since we don't know what you are seeing, I would recommend either editing your original question, or starting a new one with what exactly appears when you try to boot up, current settings (i.e. fastboot AND secure boot disabled, etc.), and what you have tried.  Sounds like you're almost there.

Comment: @bgregs https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480777/ubuntu-do-not-boot

Answer (score 1):

The `~/.local/share/Trash` directory contains 2 sub-directories, `files` and `info`.  When you move something into the trash using the GUI, it actually moves it into the files sub-directory, and may put some meta-info into the info sub-directory.  So, if you want to remove items in the Trash from the command line, you really want to do

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*/*
```

Comment: same probleme `rm: cannot remove 'file.txt': Read-only file system. any solution` i think it's a permission probleme i have only read accesson that dir

Comment: Is there a file.txt.trashinfo file in ~/.local/share/Trash/info?  If so, what is in there for the Path?

Comment: `rm: cannot remove '/home/achraf/.local/share/Trash/info/labd-1.tgz.trashinfo': Read-only file system` here is an example .

Comment: Where is /home/achraf/.local/share/Trash/info located?  Is it a NFS share, CIFS share, local directory?  There might be some permissions problem with a share preventing you from deleting it.  If it is local, you may want to run the mount command to see if it is just your local directory that is read-only, or if other filesystems are mounted read-only.  There might be an issue with your system.