# Ubuntu do not boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dual-boot, readonly

I have been workinng on ubuntu that is installed on dual boot with windows 10  for a while and yestrday a have descovred that all my files are on read only i can't modify or delete .... I found then the windows fast boot was turned on. I turned it off. In the grup when i chose ubuntu take me to a terminal. [image]

Note that secured boot i disabled too.

Comment: type fsck -f /dev/sda5 at (initramfs) to attempt to repair the filesystem

Comment: It's works thank you @bgregs can you create an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attempt to repair the file system (the error message hints at this by saying):

> UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY

This can be done by executing the following command at the (initramfs) prompt:

```
fsck -f /dev/sda5
```

Man page link for fsck: [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fsck.8.html)

**EDIT:**

This question originated because of recent Windows 10 updates (in a dual boot environment) flipping "fast-boot" back on.  The problem was documented originally here: [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/668204)

The OP had to disable fast-boot, and was then presented with the above error.  The `fsck` command finally resolved their issues.